# Firebase Storage not showing in Android Studio Assistant

Tags: firebase, storage, firebase-storage, firebase-assistant

This Project was connected to firebase storage, but suddenly it disconnected automatically. I just trying to reconnect to firebase storage, but storage are not showing in assistant please guide me.

[image: See Photo]

Comment: in photo check the last options cloud storage for firebase, that's firebase storage

Comment: What do you mean by connected? Please post any code that you are facing issues with.